# while I am trying to play with pointers in c, I faced this problem.where is the output of the program differ form the GDB could someone explain?

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to get deep  acknowledge of pointers. while I am running  this example it doesn't output any thing due to segmentation fault. But when I am trying to run the code line by line from GDB it works normally
Look at screen shot.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct s{
    int a;
    struct s* next;
    
};
struct s foo() {
    struct s m ;
    struct s f[10];
    m.a = 55;
    m.next =&(f[0]);
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 9) {
        f[i].a = 28 + i;
        f[i].next = &(f[i+1]);
        i++;
    }
    
    return f[0];
}

int main()
{
    struct s f  = (foo());
    printf("%d ",f.a);
    printf("%d ",f.next->a);
    printf("%d ",f.next->next->a);

    return 0;
}
```

if you change the main function to be like this :

```
int main(){
    struct s f = (foo());   int a = f.a;
   int b - f.next->a;
   int c = f.next->next->a;
   int d = f.next->next->next->a;
   int g = f.next->next->next->next->a;
   printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n", a, b , c ,d, g);

}
```

it will work fine.
this screen shot is n't working when I am trying to call printf directly .
[image: screeshot of the GDB debugger]

this is working when I am trying to store  in  variables first and then call printf on the variables
[image]]

Comment: `m` and `f` are allocated on the stack, so as soon as you return from `foo`, they're garbage pointers.

Comment: I understand that but ,  so do I return them from the function and store.  look at the GDB you will find it is working well

Comment: You do not store the array from the function. Only one pointer. This line breaks your memory: `f[i].next = &(f[i+1]);`

Comment: "Working well" is not the same as "it is valid code". It just may wait for a better occasion to crash and burn.

Comment: @Gerhardh look at the second screen shot when I am trying to store the values in variables it is working well. could you explain more please ?

Comment: Just read my comment above yours. Failing to crash is not an indication that it is valid.

Comment: Enable Address Sanitizer to catch such errors properly: `-fsanitize=address` (also `-fsanitize=undefined`). Example: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/axj4ocndn

Comment: @Gerhardh thank you about "if working well doesn't mean valid" , about this code f[i].next = &(f[i+1]); how come it is not valid ? I am here trying to  store address of struct element.

Comment: `&(f[i+1]);` is the address of local variable. As the very fist comment tells you, local variables are no longer valid after you leave the function. The address you point to does not belong to you any longer. Don't access it after returning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, variables that are defined inside a function are either static or automatic (auto). The default is automatic. The lifetime of automatic variables ends when the function returns and its return value has been copied to another variable or used in an expression.

```
struct s foo() {
    struct s f[10];
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 9) {
        f[i].a = 28 + i;
        f[i].next = &(f[i+1]);
        i++;
    }
    
    return f[0];
}

int main()
{
    struct s f  = (foo())
```

So after `foo`'s return value has been stored in `main`'s `f`, `foo`'s `f` array is no longer alive, and trying to access any part of it is an error.

So why does the following work?

```
   int b = f.next->a;
   int c = f.next->next->a;
   int d = f.next->next->next->a;
   int g = f.next->next->next->next->a;
   printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n", a, b , c ,d, g);
```

The reason is that your implementation of C stores automatic variables in a stack, and doesn't shrink the stack after a function finishes. Instead, the variables remain undisturbed until another function is called. That function will reuse all or part of the stack space, overwriting variables without regard to their old types. A pointer may be overwritten by an integer, or a few character of a string, or something else.

So, although it's undefined behavior and **you should never rely on this working**, you can access parts of the `f` array in this particular case because no function has been called since `foo` returned.

Similarly, in your GDB session, since you've stopped your program after `foo` returns but before *printf* has been called, GDB can safely access `f.next->next->a`, etc., but it's still undefined behavior.

Your second version *does* call functions, and that's when you're going to run into trouble.

```
    printf("%d ",f.a);
    printf("%d ",f.next->a);
    printf("%d ",f.next->next->a);
```

The first line, `printf("%d ",f.a)`, will work fine. `main`'s `f` is valid. But **the call to *printf* is going to overwrite the stack previously used by `foo`**, including all or part of what used to be `foo`'s `f` array.

Note that you won't see this output yet, because *printf* won't print out anything until you've asked it to print the end-of-line character.

The next line, `printf("%d ",f.next->a);`, is going to print a seemingly random integer, because `foo`'s `f[1].a` has been overwritten with whatever local variables *printf* uses. And, again, you won't see any output yet because of buffering.

The next line, `printf("%d ",f.next->next->a)`, is where things come crashing down. `foo`'s `f[1].next` is almost certainly not going to be a valid pointer, so you get a segmentation fault.

How can you make this work correctly? If you want `foo`'s `f` array to stay alive for the entire duration of the program, just prefix the declaration with the keyword `static`. That means there will be one copy of the `f` array, no matter how many times you call `foo`. If you want each call to `foo` to allocate a new `f` array, you can use the *malloc* function. Space allocated by *malloc* will remain alive until either you call *free* or the program exits.